# How would I implement for loop using google script to edit a google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am very new to scripting on Google form. In fact, I just recently fount out about it.

So what I'm trying to do is that I want to create a form that consists of duplicated pages in accordance to a number that is chosen by the user.

For instance, the form asks the user "How many people will be participating in this event?" If the user types in 5, the form will make 5 duplicates of a page, in which all of those pages will ask for the details of each participant.

So is there a way create duplicates of a page using a for loop?

Comment: I don't think you would want five pages because you still only have one user in front the screen.  What might be more valuable is to collect the five email addresses and send them invitations to participate in the event? I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to implement using [installable form-submit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) which runs when a user responds to a form.

For more information, check these two versions of the form-submit trigger:

1. [Google Forms events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_forms_events)
2. [Google Sheets events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events)

Then, when triggered, you may want to create new documents using the `append` methods in [Class Body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body).

See this related SO posts for more insights and sample codes:

- [Duplicating a page of a document and replacing text on each page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825675/duplicating-a-page-of-a-document-and-replacing-text-on-each-page)
- [Google app script copy document page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783819/google-app-script-copy-document-page)